# Write data to a field in Firebase realtime database without authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Im making a react app for music downloads. When a music is downloaded, i have a counter representing the number of times it has been downloaded, and im using a firebase transaction to update the number of time it has been downloaded:

```
  static increaseDownload(id) {  
    firebaseDB.ref("musics/" + id).transaction(musique => {
      if (musique) {
        musique.downloaded++;
      }
      return musique;
    });
  }
```

[image]

I know that according to the security rules ,users have to be authentified to wirte/read to the db, but i don't want to register and login users,and i also don't want to put ".write":true for every data in my database. I want users to be able to just go to the site and download.

My question is, how can i make the "downloaded" counter increase, allowing non-authentified users to write ONLY to that "downloaded" field ?
I want non-authentified users to write just to that "downloaded" field, every other fields, and data will not be accessible for writing without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
You can allow that 'musics' node's child which is 'downloaded' to be accessed only while other information in your database remains private and non-accessible.
add this your database rule

```js
 
{
/* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
   "rules": {
      ".read": "false",
        ".write": "false",
    
     "musics":{
     "downloaded":{
       ".read": true,
         ".write": true
       }   
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: that will also allow users to write to the "artist", "name", "url" fields in that node, and i don't want that.

Comment: you can further go to any node and apply rule for. just write "Name of node" : { ".read":true, ".write":true } .

//for your case
 "musics": {
 "downloaded":{
 ".read": true, ".write": true
 } 
}